# What is the meaning of this Decimal representation in ruby?

Tags: ruby

The number is this:

```
#<BigDecimal:9829250,'0.202499E4',18(27)>
```

If I print it, it is: `2024.99`. What is the meaning of the `9829250` (perhaps memory address?) and the `18(27)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)”. This question is asked often and there are numerous pages describing `inspect` and its output. Also Ruby tutorials and books cover `inspect` very early-on so it should be easily found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to guess when we have [documentation for BigDecimal#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-inspect)!

> #### BigDecimal#inspect()
>
> Returns debugging information about the value as a string of comma-separated values in angle brackets with a leading #:
>
> ```
> BigDecimal.new("1234.5678").inspect
> #=> "#<BigDecimal:b7ea1130,'0.12345678E4',8(12)>"
> ```
>
> The first part is the address, the second is the value as a string, and the final part ss(mm) is the current number of significant digits and the maximum number of significant digits, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you have the source installed, you can have a look there. The information below is for a local user-installation of RVM.

As a alternative to @Dogbert's answer, you can also check out the source file:

```
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.4/ext/bigdecimal/
```

If you look in `bigdecimal.c` around line 2034, you'll see the documentation:

```
/* Returns debugging information about the value as a string of comma-separated
 * values in angle brackets with a leading #:
 *
 * BigDecimal.new("1234.5678").inspect ->
 * "#<BigDecimal:b7ea1130,'0.12345678E4',8(12)>"
 *
 * The first part is the address, the second is the value as a string, and
 * the final part ss(mm) is the current number of significant digits and the
 * maximum number of significant digits, respectively.
 */
```

Comment: _Note:_ the path given will only help those using RVM.

Comment: The path can differ wildly depending on your operating system and what tools like RVM or `rbenv` are being used. On many Linux distributions unless you have the "development" version of Ruby installed you won't even have these files, and in some cases, not even then, you'll need to install from source.

Comment: It'd be simpler and less error-prone to use `ri BigDecimal#inspect` or `ri BigDecimal.inspect` from the command-line.

Comment: @theTinMan i agree, your command gives a error 'Nothing known about BigDecimal#inspect'. Im just trying to point out you can look in the source if you have it installed, as a alternative.